# Can't set the pushpin properties (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a map with `Pushpin`:

```
<maps:Map ZoomLevel="18" Height="575" x:Name="map1" Width="415" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,-10,0">
    <toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children>
        <toolkit1:Pushpin x:Name="push1" GeoCoordinate="" Content=""  Background="Gray" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template_Content}">
        </toolkit1:Pushpin>
    </toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```

I try to set properties from the code:

```
map1.Center = currentObject.Coords;
push1.GeoCoordinate = currentObject.Coords;
push1.Content = currentObject.Name;
```

So `Map` works, but `Pushpin` returns `NullReference Exception`. What the reason and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map1.Center = currentObject.Coords;
Pushpin pushpin = (Pushpin)this.FindName("push1");
pushpin .GeoCoordinate = currentObject.Coords;
pushpin .Content = currentObject.Name;
```